# How do I download the HTML5 version of a file that is stored in Box?

Tags: html, box

I have an application that reads files from *Box* (the cloud storage thing) and sends them to a content analyzer.  Unfortunately, the content analyzer can't handle PowerPoint files, so I need some way to convert them to another format, such as HTML.  I know Box can do this; but I can't figure out a way to extract the HTML5 version of the file so I can send it to the analyzer.

Is there a REST interface (or even better, a **Node.js** SDK call) that will let me extract the HTML5 version of a file from Box?

Answer (score 0):

What I needed was the *representations* API. It's explained in the SDK docs at https://github.com/box/box-node-sdk/blob/master/docs/files.md#get-representation-info.